# What is the Bremsstrahlung or dipole radiation mechanism involved in the emission of radiation by the rotating or moving charge?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

> A rotating charge such as the electron classically orbiting around the nucleus, will constantly lose energy in
>   form of electromagnetic radiation.

I asked my teacher about how this radiation is created from the charge. My teacher said that energy is usually lost by the mechanisms such as *Bremsstranhlung*, *Dipole radiation*, etc. But, I don't have these mechanisms in my text book and I need to know how these mechanisms are carried out, so that I would understand the concepts better. So, I thought Physics Stack Exchange will help me.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a classical treatment of an orbiting electron.  Quantum Mechanics solved the issue of why an electron doesn't lose energy in an atomic orbit.

Answer (score 1):

[Bremsstrahlung Radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung)

[Dipole Radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_radiation#Dipole_radiation)

Accelerated charges radiate. This is the golden rule.

The physical causes of electro-magnetic radiation are called legion for they are many. However, the mathematical mechanism is fairly straight-forward conceptually (while being a real bear in the details). Here's the basic idea: by solving [Maxwell's Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Vacuum_equations.2C_electromagnetic_waves_and_speed_of_light) one acquires a [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) for the electric and magnetic fields. These equations tell us that changes in these fields propagate away from their source at a speed $c$ (the speed of light). However, these waves carry energy with them, and by conservation of energy, the emitting sources must lose energy.

Comment: the equations can describe and predict the behavior of those legions of physical causes, which appear in the equations as boundary values.

Answer (score 0):

Bremsstrahlung is a German fancy name for a type of Electromagnetic wave (an X-Ray to be specific). According to classical electromagnetism, whenever a charged particle accelerates an electromagnetic wave is produced. The source of bremsstrahlung (or "braking radiation") is the negative acceleration of an electron in a **Coolidge tube** (Google it for the details of the experiment). Inside a Coolidge tube, collisions between electrons and metal nuclei cause rapidly moving electrons to decelerate rather quickly, thus producing a continuous spectrum in the X-Ray region.

Answer (score -1):

Brehmstrahlung is actually whenever a very fast electron enters a "medium" where the "local speed of light" e.g. a block of glass where c=0.7 is less than the speed of the electron. It's not that different from the sonic boom when a jet plane travels faster than the local speed of sound.

Comment: Are you not confusing Brehmstrahlung with Cherenkov radiation? I believe that what you just described is Cherenkov.

Comment: Of course you're right...my bad.

Comment: -1 because it does not answer the question. maybe you should delete it?